# correcting my sql query in suitable form

Tags: mysql

I am trying below query in my sql please correct below query in executable form or tell me why am I geting some error...

**Query**

```
SELECT {0},{1},count(distinct(p.id)),sum(oi.cout),
ROUND(sum(p.orderAmount),2),if({41}='ALL','ALL',concat(s.name,' (',s.code,')')) 
FROM supplier s, purchaseorder p
left outer join (select o.orderId oid,count(o.id) cout from orderitem o group by o.orderId)oi
on oi.oid=p.id
where p.supplierid IN ({3}) and p.submittedBy IS NOT NULL 
and  s.id=p.supplierid and p.orderdate between {0} and {1}
```

**Error**

> Error :-SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0},{1},count(distinct(p.id)),sum(oi.cout),ROUND(sum(p.orderAmount),2),if({41}='A' at line 1

Comment: This simply is invalid syntax: `SELECT {0},{1}....`. What are you trying to do there? What are the curly backets for?

Comment: So tell us about curly brackets

Comment: As arkascha alludes to, you need to have to fill in the {0},{1} using string.format

Comment: This `{41}` makes me think that this query is part of a bigger snippet, and that you'll have a good time dealing with your `string.Format`...

Comment: Maybe Lokesh means {4}

Comment: @tofutim I guess so, but as far as I can see, maybe he can't be sure. Maybe the guy who wrote this query meant `{1}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{0}` is not a valid name of a field (column) in a table in MySQL. So is `{1}` and etc.

Comment: Which has already been mentioned several times in the comments above.

Comment: Dude, you have 14k reputation, give it up a bit eh? ;)